# Fetching Data from a Remote Server and Inserting it into local database Table directly

Tags: mysql

I trying to run a select "concat insert query" withing select statement from a local mysql server and fetch some fragmentation related meta data from a remote server and insert that data into database tables on local server, i haven't tried this approach before and no web pages found regarding this online , can i have some suggestion from anyone who is familier with this approach.

My whole idea was to run a select query on local server and fetch some data from remote server and directly insert that data into local server database tables .

I am using MySQL on both the server,

i am pasting my query here can someone help me regarding this

### Query:

mysql -sN -uxxxx -pxxxxx -h xxxxxx -e "
select concat('insert into reporting.fragmentation values(' "'", @@hostname ,"'" ',' "'", table_schema ,"'" ',' "'", table_name ,"'" ',' 
"'", concat(round(table_rows/1000000,2), 'M') ,"'" ',' "'", concat(round((data_length+index_length)/(1024*1024*1024), 2), 'G') ,"'" ',' 
"'", concat(round(data_length / (1024*1024*1024),2),'G') ,"'" ',' "'", concat(round(index_length / (1024*1024*1024),2),'G') ,"'" ',' 
"'", round(data_length/1024/1024) ,"'" ',' "'", round(index_length/1024/1024) ,"'" ',' "'", (data_free/(index_length+data_length)) ,"'" ',' 
"'", now() ,"'" ');') 
from information_schema.tables 
where TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN ('information_schema','mysql','sys','performance_schema') 
and 
round(data_free/1024/1024) > 500 
and 
table_schema like 'livedriveusers_%'"

Comment: just a small update , when i am running the inner query after logging into mysql i am getting insert statements as required, but when running from shell i am getting the below output

Comment: just a small update , when i am running the inner query after logging into mysql i am getting insert statements as required, but when running from shell i am getting the below output: insert into reporting.fragmentation values(, @@hostname ,,, table_schema ,,, table_name,,, concat(round(table_rows/1000000,2), M) ,,, concat(round((data_length+index_length)/(1024*1024*1024), 2), G) ,,, concat(round(data_length/(1024*1024*1024),2),G) ,,, concat(round(index_length/ (1024*1024*1024),2),G) ,,, round(data_length/1024/1024) ,,, round(index_length/1024/1024) ,,,(data_free/(index_length+data_length)),);

Comment: I am not getting what you are trying to achieve. but take a look at my post https://stackoverflow.com/a/60460836/5193536

Comment: Something pt-archiver is built to do as well